# Using SharePoint online "working on it..." on Ajax call in web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, ajax

I have a SharePoint add-in and I wanted to check if it is possible to display SharePoint online "Working on it.." during an ajax call from a client side web part.

Answer (score 1):

You will get an idea from this,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loading').hide();
    }); 

    $(document)
          .ajaxStart(function () {
            $('#loading').show();
          })
          .ajaxStop(function () {
            $('#loading').hide();
          });
    </script>

    <div id='loading'><img id=\"loadingImg\" src=\"ajaxloader.gif\"style=\"width:70px;height:70px;position:relative;\"/><br/><span id=\"Status\">Working on it...</span>
    </div>
```

You can hide/show div according to your requirements and also you have to set your image path in img source & adjust css.

Comment: Thanks Vishal for your reply! 

Is it possible to use the one that SharePoint online provides?